# Magento 2 Product detail page " The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed." error

Tags: product, magento2.3

I am getting below error on product detail page

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element
>   'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is
>   not allowed. Line: 1197

```
Magento version : 2.3.2
PHP version :7.2
```

I have disabled all custom module and removed "ifconfig" from my custom theme but not got any clue.

Please share your ideas what could be issue.

Comment: check log file I think in the log file showing full error

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. I fixed this issue by remove `ifconfig` for `referenceBlock` in my custom module xml file.

**Reason**: You can use ifconfig attributes only on block, ui_component, action.
referenceBlock does not allow this attribute.

So kindly check ifconfig in your project.

The following command will be useful for you.

```
grep -r "ifconfig" app/
```

Then find your issued XML easily

Comment: ,I have already grep searched in app folder.I found "ifconfig" in many places including Amasty module and I disabled these module but still not working.

Comment: Hi akgola. In my case, I did not disable any module., just remove ifconfig for referenceBlock from all XML file.

Comment: I think, you should remove ifconfig from referenceblock tag from the layout XML and remove cache rm -rf var/* generated/* and check. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Exactly. What I did

Comment: Hi akgola. did you solve this issue?

Comment: @ Arunprabakaran ,still not.I have already did all things many times but not got any solution.